# Check passed argument's data type through phpunit

Tags: arguments, phpunit, instance

Using PHPUnit I want to check the passed argument to my class constructor has the correct data type and throw an exception but I'm stuck how to implement it.

Say I have this sample class:

```
Class Foo {
    public function __construct(Bar $bar) {
        if (!($bar instanceof Bar)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
/**
 * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function test_it_has_the_correct_data_type() {
    $foo = new Foo('bar') // having this line will result to must be an instance of Bar error message
}
```

Comment: actually no need, PHP will not allow to call the constructor because of wrong type of the argument passed, it will end with an error smth like `...Argument 1 passed to Foo::__construct() must be an instance of Bar, string given, called in...`  actually that's the point of typehinting -- you prevent passing an argument of wrong type.